# Angular 'saveAs' function

Tags: angular, save-as

I am using the following function to save string to a file,

However instead of saving the file to c:/ drive it saves to Downloads folder with the name "C:\Log.txt", how can I specify the location?

```
  Save(log: string): void {
    saveAs(new Blob([log], { type: "text" }), 'C:\\Log.txt');
  }
```

Comment: Where is this saveAs coming from ? Can you create a stackblitz

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine where the browser will save the file, independent of the framework you are using.

This happens due to browser security reasons. The user filesystem cannot be accessed by the JavaScript or HTML, otherwise you could place some malware on user's system.

Comment: Is there a possibility to save the logs to the same file? otherwise every time the log function is called a new file is downloaded.

Comment: No, you can't. Since the browser will see a file with the same name it will append a incremental number at the end to avoid overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using saveAs from a file-saver library, the second parameter is responsible for the name of the file, not its location.

the browser cannot decide where to save a file, it's unique to the local machine.